# ComputerCraft Twitch Follower Program Not Working

Tags: minecraft, computercraft

I have a program on Computercraft named Twitch that shows how many veiwers and followers I have on Twitch. When I try to run it it gives me this error:

> twitch:39: attempt to index
>
> ? (a nul value)

The code is:

```
    -- Written By Bacon_Donut
-- http://twitch.tv/bacon_donut
-- API call updated by @darkgoldblade on twitter

-- View all my public pastebin codes at:
-- http://pastebin.com/u/bacon_donut

-- This is formatted to fit on a 1x3 wall of Advanced Monitors
-- with an Advanced Computer on the left side.
-- To get this to work you need to edit the streamid variable then run these four commands:

-- label set SomeKindOfNameHere
-- pastebin get 4nRg9CHU json
-- pastebin get vhn1z23v startup
-- startup

-- ChangeLog:
-- Feb 16, 2015 - @CoolAcid
-- Added automatic download of JSON parser
-- Fixed the offline streamer detection
-- Added last follower option

-- Twitch Name of the Streamer
streamid = "Bacon_Donut"


-- SleepTime is how often to grab new data. Set here to one minute.
-- Set it too fast and twitch will flag you for spam
-- and stop giving you data
SleepTime = 60

if not fs.exists('json') then
        write("JSON API not found - Downloading")
        shell.run("pastebin get 4nRg9CHU json")
end

os.loadAPI("json")
local m = peripheral.wrap("right")
m.setCursorPos(1,1)

function getFollowers()

        str = http.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" .. streamid .. "/follows?limit=1").readAll()
        obj = json.decode(str)
        follows = json.encodePretty(obj._total)

        m.setCursorPos(1,3)    
        m.write("Twitch Followers: ")
        m.write(follows)

        return follows
end

function getFollower()

        str = http.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" .. streamid .. "/follows?limit=1").readAll()
        obj = json.decode(str)
        follower = json.encodePretty(obj.follows[1].user.name)

        m.setCursorPos(1,5)    
        m.write("Follower: ")
        m.write(follower)

        return follows
end

function getViewerCount()
        lstr = http.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" .. streamid).readAll()
        lobj = json.decode(lstr)
        m.setCursorPos(1,1)


        if lobj.stream == nil then
                m.write(streamid)
                m.setCursorPos(1,4)
                m.write("Live Viewers: Offline")
        else
                live = json.encodePretty(lobj.stream.viewers)
                m.setBackgroundColor(colors.yellow)
                m.clear()
                m.write(streamid)
                m.setCursorPos(1,4)
                m.write("Live Viewers: ")
                m.write(live)          
        end

        return live
end

while true do
        m.setCursorPos(1,1)
        m.setBackgroundColor(colors.white)
        m.setTextColor(colors.blue)
        m.setTextScale(1)
        m.clear()

        m.write(streamid)
        m.setCursorPos(1,4)

        local status, live = pcall(function () getViewerCount() end)

        if status then
                -- do nothing
        else
                m.write("Live Viewers: Loading...")
        end

        local status, followsCount = pcall(function () getFollowers() end)

        m.setCursorPos(1,3)    

        if status then         
                -- do nothing
        else           
                m.write("Twitch Follows: Loading...")
        end

        m.setCursorPos(1,5)    

        local status, live = pcall(function () getFollower() end)

        if status then
                -- do nothing
        else
                m.write("Follower: Loading...")
        end



        sleep(SleepTime)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Lee Yi is incorrect in his assumption.

Considering that your error is specifically, Attempt to index ? (a nil value), then that means that m is nil. In other words, you need to put a peripheral, (In this case I'm assuming a monitor) to the right of the computer.

From the code:

```
-- This is formatted to fit on a 1x3 wall of Advanced Monitors
-- with an Advanced Computer on the left side.
```

So you need the monitors, ON THE RIGHT.

Perhaps you should read the instructions provided with someone else's code rather than wondering why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The peripheral you wrapped doesn't actually have the ability to `setCursorPos()`

**Sidenote:**

Multi line comments are usually done like this:

```
--[[
Stuff here is a comment
]]--
```

Comment: Some People prefer multiple single-line comments over the multi-line comment blocks